# how to autogenerate page on github ver.2.41 windows.1?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-for-windows, auto-generate

I wanna generate a page with at least a default theme and is auto-filled. How do I do that? [I'm new to all of this and tryna learn :(.]

I did generate a page but it was just a plain white page with only the name of my repository :(.